# Why there are `/lib` and `/lib64` but only `/bin`?

Tags: linux, android, architecture

In my laptop:

```
$ cat /etc/issue  
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS \n \l
```

There are two different folders for libraries `x86` and `x86_64`:

```
~$ ls -1 /  
bin
lib
lib64
sbin
...
```

Why for binaries exists only one directory?

P.S. I'm also interested in Android but I hope that answer should be the same.

Comment: Only in one? I see both `/bin` and `/sbin` there. What is the question? Are you asking about the difference between `/lib` and `/lib64`?

Comment: @Kusalananda, I mean that there is no independent folder for `x86_64` (neither for `/bin` no for `/sbin`).

Comment: IMO OP wants to know why there is no `/bin64`.

Comment: The approximately one application that benefits from having both 32-bit and 64-bit versions (WINE) gets around it by having different-named binaries (`wine*32` and `wine*64`).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: it also needs to be said that you link binaries against libraries, not vice versa. So binaries don't need to be partitioned by 32/64-bitness.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First, why there are separate `/lib` and `/lib64`:

The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf)
mentions that separate `/lib` and `/lib64` exist because:

> 10.1. There may be one or more variants of the /lib directory on systems which support more than one binary format requiring
>   separate libraries. (...) This is commonly used for 64-bit or 32-bit
>   support on systems which support multiple binary formats, but require
>   libraries of the same name. In this case, /lib32 and /lib64 might be
>   the library directories, and /lib a symlink to one of them.

On my Slackware 14.2 for example there are `/lib` and `/lib64`
directories for 32-bit and 64-bit libraries respectively even though
`/lib` is not as a symlink as the FHS snippet would suggest:

```
$ ls -l /lib/libc.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Aug 11  2016 /lib/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.23.so
$ ls -l /lib64/libc.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Aug 11  2016 /lib64/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.23.so
```

There are two `libc.so.6` libraries in `/lib` and `/lib64`.

Each dynamically built
[ELF binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)
contains a hardcoded path to the interpreter, in this case either
`/lib/ld-linux.so.2` or `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`:

```
$ file main
main: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, not stripped
$ readelf  -a main  | grep 'Requesting program interpreter'
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]

$ file ./main64
./main64: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, not stripped
$ readelf  -a main64  | grep 'Requesting program interpreter'
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

The job of the interpreter is to load necessary shared libraries.  You
can ask a GNU interpreter what libraries it would load without even
running a binary using `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1` or a `ldd` wrapper:

```
$ LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 ./main
        linux-gate.so.1 (0xf77a9000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf760e000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77aa000)
$ LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 ./main64
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd535b3000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f56830b3000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f568347c000)
```

As you can see a given interpreter knows exactly where to look for
libraries - 32-bit version looks for libraries in `/lib` and 64-bit
version looks for libraries in `/lib64`.

FHS standard says the following about `/bin`:

> /bin contains commands that may be used by both the system
>   administrator and by users, but which are required when no other
>   filesystems are mounted (e.g. in single user mode). It may also
>   contain commands which are used indirectly by scripts.

IMO the reason why there are no separate `/bin` and `/bin64` is that if we had
the file with the same name in both of these directories we couldn't call one of them
indirectly because we'd have to put `/bin` or `/bin64` first in
`$PATH`.

However, notice that the above is just the convention - the Linux
kernel does not really care if you have separate `/bin` and `/bin64`.
If you want them, you can create them and setup your system accordingly.

You also mentioned Android - note that except for running a modified
Linux kernel it has nothing to do with GNU systems such as
Ubuntu - no glibc, no bash (by default, you can of course compile and deploy it manually), and also directory structure is
completely different.

Comment: Your `ls -l` examples aren't particularly germane. What *would* be useful is the output of `ls -l /lib /lib64`, which probably shows that *`/lib` itself* is a symlink.

Comment: You meant `ls -ld`, and no, `/lib` is not a symlink on my `Slackware 14.2` system.

Comment: Libraries have different md5sums: `dfd029d25c58831bc5db671aec99a36f  /lib64/libc.so.6`, `987e7b736f316cc8da87ca2f38dae93e  /lib/libc.so.6`.

Comment: In that case, showing the symlinks in-directory doesn't connect to the citation.

Comment: Ah, right, it isn't.  I think that `and /lib a symlink to one of
them.` should be read as `and /lib might a symlink to one of them.`.
Notice that they used `might` in the previous part of the sentence.  I
also checked that on `Ubuntu` `/lib` is not a symlink just like on
`Slackware`.  Also `man hier` does not mention any `/lib` symlinks.
I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Interestingly, on `Arch` for example `/lib` is a symlink to
`/usr/lib`.

Comment: LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 is obsolete due to a security hole and ldd doesn't use it anymore. Reason: ldd /path/to/malicious-static-binary was used to take over systems because sysadmins were expecting ldd to only look at the binary not run it. Also, checking for static or not is inadequate as a binary can be constructed to use a malicious loader instead.

Answer (score 23):

The reason is that the lib/lib64 directories can contain files which happen to have the same **name** because those are libraries shared with diverse programs.  Putting them in separate directories solves the conflict.  There's (usually...) no good reason for distributing same-named executables on the same system which are 32/64-bit, but since there can be a mixture of executables, the shared libraries have to be provided for.